Problem store and get image file from storage path of laravel
I'm struggling to find what I have missed in my code; I can store image name in my table but can't store image file in folder storage/app/public and can't display image in my browser when using http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/H9WZXTgwoSsAAHOeWQVlk5o9oOcLvoDp.jpg (that gives me not found), when fetching data by Postman I can get the image name file but not the file image in my react js ui, when looking at storage/app/public/ it's empty, same thing in public/storage, I have made a storage link (php artisan storage:link).  I'm confused, this is my controller code:
 public function index()
{
    $projects = Project::all();
    return response()->json(
        $projects
    );
}


public function store(ProjectRequest $request)
{
    // dd($request);
    try {
        $imageName = Str::random(32).".".$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        // Create Product
        Project::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'image' => $imageName,
            'url' => $request->url,
            'github'=>$request->github
        ]);
        // Save Image in Storage folder
        Storage::disk('public')->put($imageName, file_get_contents($request->image));
        // Return Json Response
        return response()->json([
            'message' => "Product successfully created."
        ],200);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // Return Json Response
        return response()->json([
            'message' => "Something went really wrong!"
        ],500);
    }
}

my Projectrequest:
class ProjectRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     */
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule|array<mixed>|string>
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            "name"=>"required",
            "image"=>"|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg,word,pdf",
            "url"=>"required",
            "github"=>"required",

        ];
    }
}

Please can you help?
